# Trouble with the [cryptogram] tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retagging

Currently, the [cryptogram](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cryptogram) tag is the primary tag, with synonyms [code](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code) and [cipher](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cipher) - it shouldn't be, though.

Cryptograms refer to a specific type of puzzle: one in which each letter has been replaced with another letter (or number, symbol, etc.). Cryptograms are always simple substitution ciphers. However, many of the puzzles in our [cryptograms](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cryptograms) tag are unrelated to cryptograms. They could be tagged as [cipher](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cipher)s or [steganography](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/steganography), but cryptograms are a *subtype* of cipher, not a synonym.

What should we do about this?

Comment: [tag:cryptograms] now points to [tag:cipher]. The tags [tag:encoded-message] and [tag:code] have been changed from pointing to [tag:cryptograms] to [tag:cipher] as well.

Answer (score 7):

I wholeheartedly agree!  I've always wondered why [cryptogram](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cryptogram) was used when it really should be [cipher](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cipher).

> #### I vote for changing the primary tag to [cipher](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cipher), and making [cryptogram](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cryptogram) a synonym of it.

Comment: So, out of curiosity (not being hugely into cryptography), how should [tag:cipher] differ from [tag:cryptography]? Isn't a cipher just the mechanism employed in cryptography?

Comment: @Alconja: From my experience, ciphers are generally doable by hand, while cryptography implies more complex mathematical concepts (number theory mostly). For instance, rot13 is a cipher but not very much cryptography, and RSA encryption is cryptography but not really a cipher.