# Cryptography and Steganography

Tags: discussion, tags

We have two tags:

- [cryptography](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cryptography)
- [steganography](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/steganography)

After the [recent boom of steganography puzzles](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/steganography), which have been well received, do we really need [cryptography](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cryptography)?

Here are the two tag wiki excerpts:

> [Steganography](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tags/steganography/info):
>
> Hidden data concealed in otherwise unsuspicious pictures, text, and/or audio.

And

> [Cryptography](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tags/cryptography/info):
>
> A puzzle concerning techniques for secure communication in the presence of (hostile) third parties.

To me they are both the same thing - hidden data.

The only differences I see is that [cryptography](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cryptography) mentions (hostile) third parties...

## Do we need both tags?

Comment: I don't think the tags are synonymous, because cryptographic algorithms usually don't *hide* plaintext in unsuspicious data, but rather "change" them to make them "unreadable". E.g. Steganography = "**T**his is a compl**e**tely unsu**s**picious **t**ext" but Cryptography = "Tltke".

Answer (score 8):

### Cryptography and steganography are two very different things...

Both involve concealing a secret message so that its meaning is not apparent, but in cryptography the message is hidden within apparent gibberish, while in steganography it's hidden within a different message which seems to have a totally innocuous meaning. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steganography):

> The advantage of steganography over cryptography alone is that the intended secret message does not attract attention to itself as an object of scrutiny. Plainly visible encrypted messages—no matter how unbreakable—arouse interest, and may in themselves be incriminating in countries where encryption is illegal. Thus, whereas cryptography is the practice of protecting the contents of a message alone, steganography is concerned with concealing the fact that a secret message is being sent, as well as concealing the contents of the message.

### ... but maybe we should lose the [cryptography](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cryptography) tag anyway.

There is much confusion over terminology in this area of knowledge. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptography#Terminology) (emphasis mostly mine):

> Until modern times, **cryptography** referred almost exclusively to encryption, which is the process of converting ordinary information (called plaintext) into unintelligible text (called ciphertext).[10] Decryption is the reverse, in other words, moving from the unintelligible ciphertext back to plaintext. A **cipher** (or **cypher**) is a pair of algorithms that create the encryption and the reversing decryption.
>
> [...]
>
> In colloquial use, the term "**code**" is often used to mean any method of encryption or concealment of meaning. However, in cryptography, code has a more specific meaning. It means the replacement of a unit of plaintext (i.e., a meaningful word or phrase) with a code word (for example, "wallaby" replaces "attack at dawn").
>
> **Cryptanalysis** is the term used for the study of methods for obtaining the meaning of encrypted information without access to the key normally required to do so; i.e., it is the study of how to crack encryption algorithms or their implementations.
>
> Some use the terms cryptography and **cryptology** interchangeably in English, while others (including US military practice generally) use cryptography to refer specifically to the use and practice of cryptographic techniques and cryptology to refer to the combined study of cryptography and cryptanalysis.

So what does this tell us about how we should use the tags on PSE? Well, I have two different suggestions for that:

1. **Synonymise [cryptography](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cryptography) and [ciphers](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ciphers).**

   [As we can see](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tags/cipher/synonyms), [code](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/code) and [cryptograms](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cryptograms), as well as [encoded-message](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/encoded-message) and [cipher](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cipher), already count as synonyms of the master tag [cipher](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cipher). (It's taken [quite](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2854/please-vote-on-whether-to-make-tagcode-a-synonym-of-tagcryptograms) a [while](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3146/should-we-merge-tagcryptograms-and-tagencoded-message/3147#3147) to [get there](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4562/trouble-with-the-cryptogram-tag?rq=1) though!) Now codes and ciphers are technically two different things (ciphers usually replace each *letter* of the plaintext with a different letter or symbol, while codes replace *words* of the plaintext with different words or phrases. If these two separate concepts are considered similar enough to be synonymised on PSE, we may as well put the whole of cryptography under the one tag.
2. **Use [cryptography](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cryptography) only for questions *about* cryptography rather than "decrypt the cipher" puzzles.**

   Until today I thought this *was* how [cryptography](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cryptography) was being used already. It seems that my perception was more or less correct about a year ago, when it was questions such as [How can our secret agent produce a cryptographically secure random number?](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/23562/how-can-our-secret-agent-produce-a-cryptographically-secure-random-number) and [Snow White and the Secret Message (Secret Sharing Problem)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/11814/snow-white-and-the-secret-message-secret-sharing-problem) and [Two Sheriffs and Eavesdroppers](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/11267/two-sheriffs-and-eavesdroppers) and [A Game of Phones](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/12411/a-game-of-phones) that bore the tag. But standards have apparently slipped since then, and this tag is now being used for actual cipher puzzles, on which it might as well be replaced by [cipher](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cipher).

Proposition 1 would be simpler to implement, but I'm not sure if all the questions tagged [cryptography](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cryptography) would really fit with the [cipher](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cipher) tag. Modern cryptography has advanced further than simple ciphers, and covers things like the RSA algorithm too.

Proposition 2 would involve retagging a bunch of questions 'inappropriately' tagged [cryptography](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cryptography) and editing the tag wiki to clarify its usage. This could take a while, but once it's done, we would at least have clear usage guidance for the tags covering two separate types of question.

Comment: I would prefer option 1.

Comment: I would prefer option 2.